# How to process GeoJSON data and create hive table for spatial analysis

Tags: postgis, spatial-analyst, hive, hadoop, gis-tools-hadoop

I am using the ESRI-GIS tool for hadoop for analyzing json data generated through ESRI products like ArcGIS. But I wanted to analyze spatial data from a PostGIS table for which I made geojson formatted data from QGIS. When I tried to create hive table using this data and using the ESRI GIS tool for hadoop, the data is not getting loaded.

I tried different ways but failed. Are there any other ways that I can follow and proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could detail a bit more the attempts you made, in order to understand what happened.

In any case, from my experience there is not a *smooth* pipeline to import things from PostGIS (or any OGC standard) to Hadoop GIS, which is a shame... ESRI has ticked the box of Free and Open Source Software by providing this tool (which by the way, it is one of the few that I know that adds spatial support to BigData), but has failed on the interoperability.
AFAIK, the support they give for loading spatial types covers their [proprietary JSON format](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/wiki/JSON-Utilities), which is not really convenient unless you are using ArcGIS...
What I have done up to now, was exporting the data from PostGIS as either WKT or GeoJSON, and then load it into hive using the csv deserializer.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE grid_10 (id bigint, json STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://some-url/data/grids/geojson';
```

This means the geometry is actually stored as text, but you can easily instantiated on the go for your queries, using the ST_GeomFromGeoJSON or ST_GeomFromText functions. For instance:

```
create table grid_cnt as 
SELECT grid_10.id, count(grid_10.id) as ptcnt FROM grid_10 JOIN tweets     WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(grid_10.json),ST_Point(tweets.longitude,   tweets.latitude))=true GROUP BY grid_10.id;
```

What I actually failed to do, and I suspect its a bug, was instantiating a spatial table with a geometric field, using this conversion. You can read more about it on my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27147274/how-to-load-spatial-data-using-the-hadoop-gis-framework).

Comment: Have you seen this https://github.com/Esri/geojson-utils.

Answer (score 1):

You may comment on requirements and use cases in the GitHub issues for [GeoJson InputFormat](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/issues/81) and [GeoJson SerDe](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/issues/80).

Update: I have opened a [merge/pull request](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/pull/96) available for review by anyone interested.

Update: the GeoJSON InputFormat and SerDe are now merged into git master.

Update: the GeoJSON InputFormat and SerDe are included in the [v1.2 pre-built JAR files](https://github.com/Esri/spatial-framework-for-hadoop/releases/latest).